# Detect dom element style change using Mutation Observer

Tags: javascript, angular

Using `MutationObserver` I would like to detect a dom element change due to media query in a component.

But the MutationObserver fails to trigger an event when the style changes.

```js
detectDivChanges() {
    const div = document.querySelector('.mydiv');
    const config = { attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true };
    const observer = new MutationObserver((mutation) => {
      console.log("div style changed");
    })
    observer.observe(div, config);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="mydiv">test</div>
```

```
.mydiv {
  height: 40px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}

@media screen and (min-width : 500px) {
  .mydiv {
    background-color: blue;
  }
}
```

Here is a [live version](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mutation-observer) of the code

Comment: `Why my code doesn't work` questions are subject to closure. Instead, could you explain what you are trying to achieve ? Since you're using Angular, there may be ways of achieving what you want without using a mutation observer.

Comment: @trichetriche, as I explained in the question,  I would like to detect the style change of the div. The breakpoint modifies the div style `background-color`. And I would like the observable to trigger an event whenever that happens

Comment: If only the background should change color, consider using [`Flex-Layout`](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout) and its breakpoints.

Comment: ngOnInit()  is called only once at intialization only

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Mutation Observer can observe changes being made **to the DOM tree**.
When your CSS MediaQuery changes, the *DOM tree* is not affected whatsoever, so the MutationObserver won't catch it.

Your confusion comes from the fact that *HTMLElement*s do have a `style` attribute. This attibute is indeed part of the DOM tree. But this `style` attribute is not the *style* that is applied on the element. This attribute does declare a StyleSheet that the *CSSOM* will parse and use if needed, but the CSSOM and the DOM are two separate things.

So what you want to detect is a CSSOM change not a DOM one (the `style` attribute doesn't change when you resize your screen), and this, a MutationObserver can't do it.

However, since you are willing to listen for a CSS MediaQuery change, then you can use the [MediaQueryList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList) interface and its [onchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList/onchange) event handler:

```js
const mediaQuery = window.matchMedia('screen and (min-width : 500px)');
mediaQuery.onchange = e => {
  console.log('mediaQuery changed', 'matches:', mediaQuery.matches);
}
```

```css
.mydiv {
  height: 40px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}

@media screen and (min-width : 500px) {
  .mydiv {
    background-color: blue;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="mydiv">test</div>
```

Comment: `Mutation observer` observes changes made to the attribute of an element. The style is a property of a dom tree element. if the changes made to the style are not watched for, what kind of attributes are taken into consideration then?

Comment: @edkeveked the `style` attribute is, but the computedStyle is not. Your CSS doesn't modify the DOM. As to *"what kind of attributes are taken into consideration then"*, all DOM attributes.

Comment: It is very surprising! Don't you mind updating your answer with that; I think it is very interesting to know

Comment: I did my best let me know if it is still not clear enough.

Comment: Good explanation by making clear the separation between the DOM and the CSSOM trees

Comment: Given the way the CCSOM processing is changing so rapidly at the moment in browsers, does anyone know if there's an alternative to mutation observers for watching changes to CSS properties, like color for example? Can't find any equivalent to window.matchMedia.